# How to make node select the least preferable parent as preferred parent in RPL protocol?

Tags: networking, protocols, routers, contiki

I would like to simulate in Cooja the following: one of the nodes selects the worst parent that provides the worst routing information as its preferred parent i.e. it  breaks the Objective Function and then updates its parent set and picks the worst parent again.

How can I do that? Will you describe to me exactly what functions or what src files that I need to use/modify to do that? Please provide me with some hints nodes.

I tried to change the two best_parent functions that I found in both src files rpl-dag.c and rpl-of0.c., but I wasn't lucky the node either kept detaching or switching between the parents.